# Deleting a row leads to error 500, internel error. #582. Google Sheet/Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-sheets, google-api

The Issue is: I am trying to deleting a row with google sheet. Here's the following code:

```
let rows: GoogleSpreadsheetRow = getSomeRows()
let row = rows.filter(...)
await row.delete()
```

The code is very simple I would like to find a specific row & delete it with the help of .delete() but I receive this error.
So I already find a solution it is simply to delete the row in the google sheet via the browser & Add new rows & boom now my library .delete() works. I can delete these new rows but i would like to understand what cause this problem, they are still rows I cannot delete them yet now but i need to delete them later.

I am receiving is this following error:

> var error = new Error(message); ^ Error: Google API error - [500]
> Internal error encountered. at createError
> (C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\Projet\Discord\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
> at settle
> (C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\Projet\Discord\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
> at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd
> (C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\Projet\Discord\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:269:11)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35) at IncomingMessage.emit
> (node:domain:489:12) at endReadableNT
> (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12) at processTicksAndRejections
> (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) { config: { url:
> ':batchUpdate', method: 'post', data:
> '{"requests":[{"deleteRange":{"range":{"sheetId":579234638,"startRowIndex":575,"endRowIndex":576},"shiftDimension":"ROWS"}}],"includeSpreadsheetInResponse":true}',
> headers: { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, /', 'Content-Type':
> 'application/json', Authorization: '
> ............', 'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.4', 'Content-Length': 160 },
> baseURL:
> 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1PlKHBLBKsKT4q-WtRhTVYi3GSQuPeJxzJePIshmAGAw',
> transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ], transformResponse:
> [ [Function: transformResponse] ], paramsSerializer: [Function:
> paramsSerializer], timeout: 0, adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
> xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
> maxContentLength: -1,

Comment: Are you sure that is the end of the error trace? It looks like there's more denoted by the comma.

Comment: I try to reproduce the error to see if i miss anything but all i get now is "Error: Google API error - [500] Internal error encountered"